# Maven generated-sources/annotations

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, annotations, maven-plugin

Hey guy's I'm posting this question having spent a good deal of time researching and not found a detailed answer.  Currently I'm having an issue with generating sources from AWS Workflow.  I'm using Maven `apt-maven-plugin` and `aspectj-maven-plugin`.  These plugins both work for generating the client classes for the activities yet fail with the following error when running `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean install` against my workflow classes.
 **Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-
plugin:1.7:compile (default) on project (myproject): Execution default
of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile failed: 
basedir (myproject)\target\generated-sources\annotations does not exist 
-> [Help 1]
```

**Plugins**

```
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        <basedir>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations</basedir>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                        <basedir>src/main/java</basedir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this issue and any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear- mvn could not find /target/generated-sources/annotations, but in pom it is stated as the source for aspectj-maven-plugin.

Does your code intend to generate sources under /target/generated-sources/annotations? If yes, then there is issue with generation, you'll need to expose more of your pom for me to tell what went wrong. If no, why not remove this part and give it another shot.

```
<source>
     <basedir>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations</basedir>
</source>
```

ps: I'd rather put this as comment but I'm not able to :(